# How to prevent monitor from blinking when I press backspace in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

How to prevent the monitor from blinking when you press backspace when there's no text left to delete in the terminal?

Comment: try my answer.

Answer (score 5):

> How to prevent the monitor from
>   blinking when you press backspace when
>   there's no text left to delete in the
>   terminal?

It is called as **visual Bell**.
You can disable this feature.

**Xterm Terminal** : [Xterm How to disable the visual bell.](https://serverfault.com/questions/67582/xterm-how-to-disable-the-visual-bell/68881#68881)

**Gnome Terminal** : Select `edit` from the *menu bar* and edit the `profile` of the terminal to *disable* it.

```
    Edit -> Current Profiles... -> Terminal bell
```

*Turn on window flashing*: In `System -> Preferences -> Sound`, Change the `Visual alert` setting to `Flash window`.

**Note**: For other terminals, search as `disable visual bell terminal name` in google search box.

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10 version 1803
To prevent monitor from blinking on pressing backspace on terminal go to

Settings -> Ease of Access -> Hearing -> Audio

On main part of the window locate "**Show Audio Alerts Visually**"

Set this to "**No visual alerts**"